# Use Convert() to add two digits the end of a number and a comma to the left?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, formatting

I'm asked to use the `CONVERT` function to return the third column as a datatype that outputs 2 digits to the right of the decimal point and all comma’s to the left (i.e. 3, 106.34). Name it FormatTotal.

This is where I'm at.

```
USE AP

SELECT InvoiceTotal,
    CAST(InvoiceTotal AS int) intTotal,
    CAST(InvoiceTotal AS decimal(8,1)) DecimalTotal
    CONVERT(decimal(???), InvoiceTotal) AS FormatTotal
FROM Invoices;
```

Comment: What is the datatype of invoiceTotal?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#money-and-smallmoney-styles

Comment: Reading the documentation is your first start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a task for `format()`:

```
format(InvoiceTotal, 'N2', 'en-US') as FormatTotal
```

`N` is the format specifier for numbers.

`2` gives you the precision (ie the number of decimal digits).

`en-US` defines the comma separator for thousands and the dot separator for decimals.